# Texstudio spellcheck popup suggestions are unreadable

Tags: texstudio

I have imported latest russian (cyrillic) dictionary from libreoffice site (as texstudio suggests). 
It correclty highlights misspelled words, but when I right-click for suggestion it shows suggesitons in unreadable wrong encoding.
The dictionary I used is [this one](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/russian-spellcheck-dictionary.-based-on-works-of-aot-group) 
[image: The croped screenshot]

This is TeXstudio 2.12.8 (hg n/a) Using Qt Version 4.8.7, compiled with Qt 4.8.7 R

Installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the suggestions in wrong encoding? And which dictionary did you download -- can you provide the link?

Comment: I edited main post. 
I am not sure what knd of encoding it is, but it's obviously wrong.

Comment: Would you mind cropping the image to only show the relevant part?

Comment: Sorry on my pc it was looks just fine. I croped it.

Comment: Check your font settings for TeXstudio: `Configure TeXstudio -> General -> Font` Which font are you using? Try changing around the fonts that you have in your system and see if there's any effect. And which version of TeXstudio is this?

Comment: I added version and platform in  main post. The changing fonts doesnt help with pop up. It changes font of the document as supposed though.

Comment: @MikeKlemin What font is that though? For example, mine is MS Shell Dlg 2, but I find the words show up fine even with a font like calibri. The fonts used in the right-click context menu is changed by that font setting, so if it's not showing up right, it's a matter of fonts on your system, in my opinion. Either that, or it's an Ubuntu thing, but I can't test that since I'm on Windows. Sorry. (but please do tell us what font that is)

Comment: This is Ubuntu Font, but it could be DejaVu sans or whatever, as I said it changes the font of the editor just fine, popu font  doesnt seems to be affected by this setting.

Answer (score 1):

All bounty for [github](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/137#issuecomment-387180789)

The issue was with bug in qt4 version. The qt5 version works flawless.